# How to fix PhantomJS rendering on AWS EC2 Ami Linux instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, phantomjs

I've built a scraping bot for a website and tested everything on my OSX.

It's look perfect, this is what I have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbK2p.jpg

And finally when I deployed to my server it looks totally strange like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEQP0.jpg

The phantomjs version are the same (2.1.1).
Just the OS are different: my Sierra OSX vs Linux AWS AMI...

Any idea?

Thank you,

Comment: Are you sure this is specific to PhantomJS? Can you get all the HTML/JS/CSS/images with `curl` or `wget` from the same EC2 instance?

Comment: yeah.. I tried to do curl and wget and it appears to download ok (html,js,css,images)... actually I'm migrating from selenium to PhantomJS, or trying to... also the fonts are very strange right? should I install fonts on the server?

Comment: It seems that a css file is not loaded when working from AWS. Is this what you see every time? Also: can you show a minimal script example? And yes, you should install fonts on the server.

Comment: I tried to login to the server and run wget in all css files and I could download that with no issues... Any other idea that I should try? How can I install the fonts and which fonts??

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the version of libfreetype.so provided by AWS, which was compiled without support for WOFF font files (libz.so).

Without compiling your own version of libfreetype, the best and easiest solution for me was using a debian based docker container.

Comment: so you use an aws ami machine with a docker container inside it?

Comment: yes, not the best way but it solved the problem without creating more issues